# Error during scipy installation using pip3

Tags: scipy, pip

Trying to install scipy on my raspberrypi (openhabian):

```
$ pip3 install scipy
```

but I get [this message](https://justpaste.it/3y6wi).

What's wrong?

Comment: please post error messages as text not pictures

Comment: looks like a lot of Scipy dependencies are missing eg LAPACK. Have you tried installing using `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy`?

Comment: @DrBwts sadly I wasn't able to post the question with the full error message. SO gave an error there ;). `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy` worked

Comment: OK I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a lot of Scipy dependencies are missing eg LAPACK.

Have you tried installing using `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy`? This will deal with any extra libraries that are needed for `Scipy` to work on your computer.